# How to create “page turn / curl” effect in FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it possible to create animation that would be similar to "page turn / curl" effect in FFmpeg between two videos? The basic idea: the first video is playing and after some time the second video is replacing the first video with this effect. On images below, blue color means the first video, black color means the second video and yellow color means the transition color between two videos.
[image: An example in images]

Answer (score 2):

You'll need (to compile) a ffmpeg build with a custom filter: https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/ffmpeg-gl-transition, or use node.js script here: https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/ffmpeg-concat

The transition is at https://gl-transitions.com/editor/InvertedPageCurl

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is it possible to use native filters of FFmpeg if I would simplify the effect this way: the second video appears from the right upper angle like on the images but  without any animation (just keep the triangle form of appearing) and replaces the first video?

Comment: A diagonal wipe? That can be done. I'll add that method within a day or two.